# Error while creating object instances in Java

Tags: java

Code:

```
 public class Dog{
        static int age;
        static String name;
        static String breed;
        public Dog(String name,int age,String breed){
            this.name=name;
            this.age=age;
            this.breed=breed;
        }
        public Dog(String name,int age){
            this(name,age,"greed");
        }
        public static void main(String args[]){
            Dog high=new Dog("luffy",19,"pomerian");
            Dog low=new Dog("gold",32,"german shepherd");
            System.out.println(low.name+" "+low.age+" "+low.breed);
            System.out.println(high.name+" "+high.age+" "+high.breed);
        }       
 }
```

Output:
`gold 32 german shepherd
gold 32 german shepherd`

Though i'm creating two object instances, only the fields of one of them are printed.Where does the bug lie?

Comment: dont use static fields

Comment: If you want a different value for each instance of your class, then don't use static. But if you want the same value for every instance of your class, then use static.

Answer (score 2):

You have used static access modifier and static variable shares memory for every class object.If you do not want then just remove static from age,name , breed

```
public class Dog{
        int age;
        String name;
        String breed;
        public Dog(String name,int age,String breed){
            this.name=name;
            this.age=age;
            this.breed=breed;
        }
        public Dog(String name,int age){
            this(name,age,"greed");
        }
        public static void main(String args[]){
            Dog high=new Dog("luffy",19,"pomerian");
            Dog low=new Dog("gold",32,"german shepherd");
            System.out.println(low.name+" "+low.age+" "+low.breed);
            System.out.println(high.name+" "+high.age+" "+high.breed);
        }       
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

All of the `static` fields are shared (`static` fields are per class), but you expected instance fields (per instance). Change

```
static int age;
static String name;
static String breed;
```

to

```
private int age;
private String name;
private String breed;
```

And you should probably have accessor (`get`ters) methods - and your printing would be simplified if you added a `toString()`. Like,

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return name + " " + age + " " + breed; 
}
```

Then you can `print` with just

```
System.out.println(low);
System.out.println(high);
```

Comment: Ah! I get it. So static is something that belongs to the class, and changes once made are reflected all over.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your code Change Static to private :

**Exmple :**

```
 public class Dog{
            private int age;
            private String name;
            private String breed;
            public Dog(String name,int age,String breed){
                this.name=name;
                this.age=age;
                this.breed=breed;
            }
            public Dog(String name,int age){
                this(name,age,"greed");
            }


            }
            public static void main(String args[]){
                Dog high=new Dog("luffy",19,"pomerian");
                Dog low=new Dog("gold",32,"german shepherd");
                System.out.println(low.name+" "+low.age+" "+low.breed);
                System.out.println(high.name+" "+high.age+" "+high.breed);
            }       
     }
```

Output :

```
luffy 19 pomerian
gold 32 german shepherd
```

And Also :

```
 public class Dog{
        private int age;
        private String name;
        private String breed;
        public Dog(String name,int age,String breed){
            this.name=name;
            this.age=age;
            this.breed=breed;
        }
        public Dog(String name,int age){
            this(name,age,"greed");
        }

        void toStrig (){
         System.out.println(name+" "+ age+" "+breed);
        }
        public static void main(String args[]){
            Dog high=new Dog("luffy",19,"pomerian");
            Dog low=new Dog("gold",32,"german shepherd");
            high.toStrig();
            low.toStrig();
        }       
 }
```

Output :

```
luffy 19 pomerian
gold 32 german shepherd
```